# How do I prevent conflicts when rebasing linear commits from one branch to another?

Tags: git, rebase, git-config, git-merge-conflict

I know there are a lot of questions about more general rebase scenarios, but I'm running into a specific one that I haven't seen addressed, unless I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Here's my situation: I create a feature branch from `master` and make some changes. While I'm waiting for a merge request back to `master` to be approved, I create a second branch from the first one and continue my work. Once the MR for the first branch is approved and merged back to `master`, it's time for me to rebase the second branch on `master` so that I have things in sync. That second action often causes a TON of merge conflicts that really shouldn't be there, even sometimes as simple as having added or removed newlines in the file.

**Before we continue, I'd like to mention that I am NOT an expert in Git, and I've not found a definitive answer on what the *correct* way is to depict branch structures. I will do my best to convey what I understand is going on, and would appreciate any advice on how to make it clearer and/or more correct. Thank you for your patience.**

Structure before the merge request is approved:

```
master    ---- X
                \
feature/1        A
                  \
feature/2          B
```

In the above diagram:

- `master` already exists. Its head is commit `X`.
- New branch `feature/1` is created based on Commit `X`.
- New commit `A` is created while on `feature/1`.
- Another new branch, `feature/2`, is created based on Commit `A`.
- New commit `B` is created while on `feature/2`.

A merge request for `feature/1` is approved, and `A` is merged into `master`, creating a merge request `M` as well. `feature/1` is NOT deleted at this time. My understanding is that Git's view of the branches now looks something like this:

```
master    ---- X - A - M   // M is a merge commit
                
feature/1 ---- X - A
                    \
feature/2            B
```

If I checkout `feature/1` and `git log`, I see:

```
feature/1 ---- X - A          // feature/1 tracks master
```

and on `feature/2`:

```
feature/2 ---- X - A - B      // feature/2 tracks feature/1
```

So now, since `master` includes Merge Commit `M` after A, I want to rebase `feature/2` on `master`. My goal:

```
feature/2 ---- X - A - M - B  // feature/2 tracks master
```

This is where the conflicts happen. Even though the code I've written in B stems directly from commit `A`, it still thinks I've introduced conflicts - sometimes even showing perfectly identical code between the two commits. This is all with the git CLI (version 2.30.0 on MacOS).

Here's a summarized list of commands I perform that results in this issue:

- `git checkout master`
- `git pull`
- `git checkout -b feature/1`
- *(write code)*, `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push`
- `git checkout -b feature/1`
- *(write code)*, `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push`
- *(`feature/1` is merged to `master`)*
- `git checkout master`
- `git pull`
- `git checkout feature/2`
- `git rebase master`
- *(resolve conflicts)*

Output of `git config --global --list`

```
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
user.name=(redacted)
user.email=(redacted)
alias.amend=commit --amend -C HEAD
core.excludesfile=/Users/(redacted)/.gitignore_global
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
pull.rebase=false
push.default=current
branch.autosetupmerge=always
```

Interestingly, one of my coworkers did the same actions using GitKraken and did NOT run into this, so this must be a configuration issue on my CLI. Anyone know what might be wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One more detail: The merge from `feature/A` to `master` occurs in a Gitlab instance, not on my local dev machine, hence checking out `master` and pulling the branch before attempting the rebase. I get the same behavior if I do `git pull --rebase origin master` .

Comment: Is the merge of the first branch done by squashing or rebasing? Anything but a _real_ merge.

Comment: We do squash commits, but this seems to happen even if there's only one commit in the branch.

Comment: That's probably the culprit. Try running the merge locally and then try to rebase your branch and let us know if you see the same crazy conflicts.

Comment: _or_, try rebasing lile this: `git rebase --onto master the-tip-of-the-original-feature1 feature2`. How does that go?

Comment: Due to security limitations on our system, I'm not going to be able to answer that directly for a little while. I cannot do a merge directly into `master` - the automation account on the Gitlab instance must do that only after the MR is approved. I'm not in a position at the moment to repro it locally, either, so it will take me a bit of time. I'll get back to you.

Comment: ? I am not asking you to do it on a public repo. You can run the merge _locally_ as an experiment to see what happens.

Comment: Something like `git checkout master-before-merging-feature-A; git merge feature-A; git branch temp; git rebase temp featureB` (that's all in local, no branches other than your _local_ `featureB` gets moved. (feel free to use commit IDs if you want to _not_ move the local branches either).

Comment: If you think you can't, it's ok.... next time you have the chance to check, keep this in mind and let us know to see how we can help.

Comment: @MattKellner you  complete the MR with squash, but still have a commit and a merge commit afterwards?

Comment: `MCA` confuses me. Doesn't `MCA` have both `M` and `A` as parents?

Comment: Gitlab does a squash for us, yes, then merges to the target branch and creates a merge commit as well. That is our current setting. I don't know if I've drawn the graph correctly - my understanding of the inner workings of Git is relatively low.

Comment: I'm confused by the ASCII art. Why does `A` exist twice? That's impossible and a commit can only exist once (and it certainly can't be its own parent).

Comment: Evidently I don't understand whatever the "standard" way to depict Git structures is, and nobody else can understand what I meant. :P I was simply trying to convey that I can see A in both branches - when `A` is merged back to `master`, `A` immediately follows `M` in the master branch while also serving as the first commit of `feature/A`. Thus, `A` is both the head commit in `master` AND the commit that `feature/B` is branched from. But as far as `feature/B` is concerned, it's still branched from `feature/A`, commit `A`, and thus has to be rebased since a merge commit follows `A` in `master`.

Comment: @MattKellner there is no such thing as "commit A on branch feature/A" and "commit A on branch master". There's only a _single_ commit A. Merging does not duplicate commits. A commit can only exist once. Multiple commits might have it in their ancestry chain, but that still doesn't make it two commits.

Comment: I know that. What else can I say to explain that the SAME COMMIT is ACCESSIBLE/VISIBLE on two different branches? I thought I already explained this at least 3 times.

Comment: I've reformatted the question to hopefully make this less confusing. Please let me know if it helps. This has been a very frustrating process.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably reapplying the commits already merged into master. You can tell rebase exactly which commits to rebase and where to apply them:

```
git rebase --onto master A feature/B
```

This will take all commits `A..feature/B` and reapply them on top of master.

Comment: Shouldn't git already understand that the only commit in between `A` and `feature/B` is the merge commit that was added when `A` was merged into `master`?

Comment: @MattKellner yes, it should; but apparently, here it fails to do so. Perhaps the automatic upstream detection of `git rebase` is failing here. You could also try `git pull --rebase`; perhaps it uses better/different heuristics.